# Mac OS Sierra gdb no symbol table info available

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gdb

I am a new user of MacOS and when using gdb, in case of segmentation faults, I get error with bt command. I am Using C++11. It does not show either source file or address. The error is like:

```
(gdb) r horse_instanced.xml 
Starting program: /Users/bhdurak/Desktop/Ceng477/hw1_solution/raytracer horse_instanced.xml
[New Thread 0x1403 of process 728]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffca1102f3 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt f
#0  0x00007fffca1102f3 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb)
```

I have made search but could not find a result. Is there any solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: can you please show how you compile your program?

Comment: Sure. Here is the inside of my makefile.  
all:
 g++ -O3 *.cpp -c -std=c++11 -march=native -g
 g++ *.o -o raytracer -lpthread

clean:
 rm -f *.o